# Syntax error : unexpected 'GET' identifier mysql

Tags: mysql

I wrote a procedure in mysql workbench 6.3CE , the prodedure didn't save and gave me the error of "Syntax error : unexpected 'GET' identifier mysql"
I wrote a procedure in mysql workbench 6.3CE , the prodedure didn't save and gave me the error of "Syntax error : unexpected 'GET' identifier mysql"

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_add`(IN obj longtext)
 BEGIN

 DECLARE errcode CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
 DECLARE errmsg TEXT; 
 DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception

BEGIN
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1

   errcode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, errmsg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
Select '-1' as State, CONCAT('SQL Exception Raised , error = ',errcode,', message = ',errmsg) as Message;
ROLLBACK;
END;
START TRANSACTION;
SET @obj = obj;
SET @vjson:= JSON_valid(@obj);  
If @vjson = 0 Then 
    Set @state = -1;
    Set @message = 'Not a Valid JSON';
Else 
    Set @action := REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@obj,'$.action'),'"','');
    Set @firstname := REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@obj,'$.firstname'),'"','');
    Set @lastname := REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@obj,'$.lastname'),'"','');
    Set @emailid := REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@obj,'$.emailid'),'"','');
    Set @password := REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@obj,'$.password'),'"','');
    Set @contactnumber := REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@obj,'$.contactnumber'),'"','');
    Set @gender := REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@obj,'$.gender'),'"','');
    Set @dob := REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@obj,'$.dob'),'"','');
    Set @userexists = (Select 1 from userbasic where emailid = @emailid and isactive = 1);
    IF isNull(@userexists) Then 
        Set @state = -1;
        Set @message = 'Not Valid User';
    ElseIF @action='basicinfo'  Then
        INSERT INTO userbasic 
    (firstname,
      lastname,
      emailid,
      password,
      mobile,
      gender,
      dob,
      createdon,
      modified,
      isactive) 
      VALUES 
      (@firstname, @lastname,@emailid,@password,@contactnumber,@gender,@dob,now(),now(),1);

        Set @state = last_insert_id();
        Set @message = 'Success';  
    Else 

        Set @state = 1;
        Set @message = 'Success';

    End IF;
END IF;
 COMMIT;
 Select @state as state, @message as message;
 END
```

Comment: What version of MySQL Server are you using? The `GET DIAGNOSTICS` statement is new as of version 5.6.4. Note MySQL Workbench has its own version numbers; it has nothing to do with the MySQL Server version.

Comment: Also you are using `JSON_EXTRACT()` which was new os of MySQL Server 5.7.8 or later. So if you are using an older version of MySQL Server, it won't work anyway.